# Mathieu Floquet solution

Tags: special-functions

Mathematica provides the `MathieuC[a,q,z]` and `MathieuS[a,q,z]` functions - as well as some other Mathieu-related functions. Maple does similarly. But in addition, Maple provides a `MathieuFloquet[a,q,z]` function.

The point is that (contrary to the Mathematica documentation) `MathieuC` and `MathieuS` do not necessarily individually satisfy the Floquet periodicity condition. But a linear combination of the two will.

The Maple documentation shows how `MathieuC[a,q,z]` and `MathieuS[a,q,z]` may be found from (linear combinations of) `MathieuFloquet[a,q,z]` and `MathieuFloquet[a,q,-z]`.

In Mathematica, I want to do the opposite; I want to get `MathieuFloquet[a,q,z]` in terms of `MathieuC[a,q,z]` and `MathieuS[a,q,z]`.

Sounds straightforward, but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: What is the definition of `MathieuFloquet[a,q,z]` in terms of the other functions?

Answer (score 1):

Up to Abramowitz, M., and Stegun, I., eds. Handbook of Mathematical Functions. New York: Dover Publications and [Maple online help](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/helpJP/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Mathieu), the following relations are valid

```
MathieuC[a, q,  x] == ( MathieuFloquet[a, q, x] + MathieuFloquet[a, q, -x])/(2*
 MathieuFloquet[a, q, 0]) && MathieuS[a, q, x] == (MathieuFloquet[a, q, x] - MathieuFloquet[a, q, -x])/(2*
 MathieuFloquetPrime[a, q, 0])
```

Then

```
Solve[%, {MathieuFloquet[a, q, x],  MathieuFloquet[a, q, -x]}]
```

> `{{MathieuFloquet[a, q, x] ->  MathieuC[a, q, x] MathieuFloquet[a, q, 0] +  MathieuFloquetPrime[a, q, 0] MathieuS[a, q, x],  MathieuFloquet[a, q, -x] ->  MathieuC[a, q, x] MathieuFloquet[a, q, 0] -  MathieuFloquetPrime[a, q, 0] MathieuS[a, q, x]}}`

does the job. Unfortunately, I don't know formulas for  `MathieuFloquetPrime[a, q, 0]` and `MathieuFloquet[a, q, 0]`.